# addFieldToFilter to column from joined table in EAV Table

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I am trying to filter columns from a joined table using `addFieldTofilter`. I have tried the code below but throws an exception.

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinInner(array('customerphotos' => $collection->getTable('myphotos/customerphotos')),
    'e.entity_id = customerphotos.customer_id',
    array(
        'customerphotos.entity_id as entity_id',
        'customerphotos.customer_id',
    ));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('customerphotos_created_at', $condition);
```

I have tried `$collection->addFilterToMap('customerphotos_created_at', 'customerphotos.created_at');` but it only works on non EAV table.

Comment: You could try $collection->getSelect()->where(YOUR_CONDITIONS);

Comment: That's how I solved it currently, but I want to use the advantage of using `addFieldToFilter`

Comment: @Ner Ever found a way to use addFieldToFilter ?